# How do you secure Apache CXF RESTful APIs?

Tags: spring-security, cxf, jax-rs

Is there an easy way to secure RESTful API exposed via Apache CXF's JAX-RS implementation?  Are there any hooks for security via Spring Security?.

I heard of people using Basic Authentication over HTTPS, but I haven't seen any actual examples. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

see http://chrisdail.com/2008/08/13/http-basic-authentication-with-apache-cxf-revisited/

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about CXF, but in Resteasy you can configure it as you would for any other web application, and then do..

```
@Context private SecurityContext sc;
```

Which allows you to check things such as `sc.isUserInRole("admin");`. CXF may provide the same functionality.